Docker container up and running on google cloud vm, but unable to visit website
I have created a multi-image website using docker compose, and I want to use google cloud to host my website. I have an image for the db, the backend, and the frontend. I have a micro e2 instance on google cloud, and have got my images up and running. I have enabled http and https traffic on the instance. The website should be accessible on port 3000.

However, when I try to visit the external ip by pasting it into my url bar, I get the "This site can't be reached" screen.
I tried messing around with the firewall settings, and using netstat to double-check that the ports are open. I even tried appending :3000 to my external ip in the url bar. Nothing seems to be working. The real issue though, is that I just don't really know what I'm doing. I have no experience with devops. Do I have to change it so my frontend is served on port 80 instead?
Additionally, I want this website to be connected to a subdomain to a domain I own, purchased from namecheap. Is there anything else I need to do to make that possible?

IIUC you've enabled access to the VM on ports 80 (http) and 443 (https) but your containers aren't listening on those ports. You will want to either expose your frontend's port through the Cloud Firewall or add a proxy that acquires a TLS cert for you and proxies your frontend.

Regarding firewall, make sure that the network tag of your instance is also the same with the firewall rule created under target tags or at least the target tags configuration is on “All instance in the network”
Also make sure that the VPC network of your instance is also the same as configure in your firewall rule network.
Make sure that there is a service listening to the port configured in your instance, because even if the port is already open from your firewall as long as there is no service listening to the port still it will not connect.
You can also use connectivity test to diagnose where the traffic is failing.
You can create a subdomain in your DNS depending what DNS vendor you are using. If by chance you are using namecheap’s DNS you can follow this link on how to create cname record.
